# mysql function for Encrypt/Decrypt like java

Tags: java, mysql, encryption

how can I simulate this code in mysql:

**Encrypt**

```
TextEncryptor encryptor = Encryptors.text(key, salt);
encryptor.encrypt(message);
```

**Decrypt**

```
TextEncryptor decryptor = Encryptors.text(key, salt);
decryptor.decrypt(message);
```

I need decrypt the data from the db that I encrytp in java code.

Comment: What is `Encryptors` and `TextEncryptor`?

Answer (score 1):

Use AES_ENCRYPT / AES_DECRYPT

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, AES_ENCRYPT('text',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')));
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt

Answer (score 0):

Mysql offers a range of [encryption functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html), out of which only aes_encrypt() has not been deprecated yet.

However, if you want to encrypt data stored in databases, you may consider applying encryption on an operating system or [database product level](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/encryption.html), so your data is encrypted, but you can still use sql to filter your data without much inconvenience.

Comment: I need decrypt the data from db that I encrypted from java code

Comment: Well, you should have said this in the question. Then, then answer is: check what algorithm the java class in your code uses and see if it has any corresponding encryption function within mysql via the link I provided. My guess is that there will not be any.